# Phpunit - Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHP\Invoker.php'

Tags: php, phpunit

I am practicing very basic unit testing following a book and the code are working fine. But every time a test fails, I get the following error which prevents displaying complete failure messages of my test:

```
C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit>phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\phpunit.xml

.....

Time: 156 ms, Memory: 2.25Mb

OK (5 tests, 5 assertions)

C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit>phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.38 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\phpunit.xml

....F.

Time: 109 ms, Memory: 2.25Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) CardTest::testIsInMatchingSet with data set #2 (Card, false, 'should not match')

    Warning: require(PHP\Invoker.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\test-bootstrap.php on line 5

    Call Stack:
        0.0000     127408   1. {main}() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:0
        0.0000     333752   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:63
        0.0000     337152   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
        0.0312    1643576   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
        0.1092    2224520   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printResult() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:356
        0.1248    2224704   6. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printFailures() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:163
        0.1248    2224832   7. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefects() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:307
        0.1248    2225088   8. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefect() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:225
        0.1404    2225560   9. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefectTrace() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:238
        0.1404    2239120  10. PHPUnit_Util_Filter::getFilteredStacktrace() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:274
        0.1404    2239400  11. PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::phpunitFiles() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Filter.php:76
        0.2340    2322608  12. PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:389
        0.2340    2322672  13. class_exists() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:410
        0.2340    2322856  14. spl_autoload_call() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:410
        0.2340    2322968  15. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::{closure:C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\test-bootstrap.php:3-6}() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:0


    Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'PHP\Invoker.php' (include_path='C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\src;C://phpunit//vendor;C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\src;C://phpunit//vendor;C:\phpunit\vend
    or/phpunit/php-text-template;C:\phpunit\vendor/phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects;C:\phpunit\vendor/phpunit/php-timer;C:\phpunit\vendor/phpunit/php-token-stream;C:\phpunit\vendor/phpunit/php-file-iterator;C
    :\phpunit\vendor/phpunit/php-code-coverage;C:\phpunit\vendor/phpunit/phpunit;C:\phpunit\vendor/symfony/yaml;.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\test-bootstrap.php on line 5

    Call Stack:
        0.0000     127408   1. {main}() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:0
        0.0000     333752   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\composer\bin\phpunit:63
        0.0000     337152   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:129
        0.0312    1643576   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\Command.php:176
        0.1092    2224520   5. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printResult() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner.php:356
        0.1248    2224704   6. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printFailures() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:163
        0.1248    2224832   7. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefects() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:307
        0.1248    2225088   8. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefect() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:225
        0.1404    2225560   9. PHPUnit_TextUI_ResultPrinter->printDefectTrace() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:238
        0.1404    2239120  10. PHPUnit_Util_Filter::getFilteredStacktrace() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php:274
        0.1404    2239400  11. PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::phpunitFiles() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\Filter.php:76
        0.2340    2322608  12. PHPUnit_Util_GlobalState::addDirectoryContainingClassToPHPUnitFilesList() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:389
        0.2340    2322672  13. class_exists() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:410
        0.2340    2322856  14. spl_autoload_call() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:410
        0.2340    2322968  15. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::{closure:C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\test-bootstrap.php:3-6}() C:\phpunit\vendor\phpunit\phpunit\PHPUnit\Util\GlobalState.php:0
```

Comment: The require will be relative to the directory that your file is executing in. Since your file is `C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\test-bootstrap.php` and your require is `require(PHP\Invoker.php)` it should be looking for the file at `C:\wamp\www\project-phpunit\PHP\Invoker.php`. Does that location exist?...

Comment: can you show us the require('PHP/Invoker.php') maybe?, and does PHP/invoker.php even exist?

Comment: The location does not exist and I could not find any PHP/Invoker.php.

Comment: May be it is referring to php-invoker(https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-invoker/tree/master/PHP). But the book did not install this package.

Answer (score 3):

The root cause for this PHP_Invoker error seems to be in the autoloader.

When PHPunit runs, it checks for existence of certain classes with class_exists function. By default this function tries to load the class with the autoloader.

If the autoloader implementation is such that it fails when the class is not found, then you will run into this error.

Example of an autoloader implementation that causes trouble is below. If the file is not found, the require_once will fail.

```
function AutoLoader($className)
{
  $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$className) . ".php";
  require_once($file);
}
```

If you have your own autoloader, one solution is to add a file_exists check there:

```
function AutoLoader($className)
{
  $file = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\',DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$className) . ".php";
  if(file_exists($file)
    require_once($file);
}
```

Reference: Discussion in the YII Framework issue tracker: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/issues/1907

Answer (score 0):

PHP_Invoker is an optional dependency of PHPUnit. You should not include `PHP/Invoker.php` (or any of the package's source files) manually.